# Does CopyFile place any lock on the source file?

Tags: windows, winapi, createfile, file-locking, file-copying

When I copy a file with [`CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), will the source file be locked in any way?
Say - if the copy operation starts, and then someone wants to open the *source* file, will it succeed? What if the "someone" requests exclusive access to the file, will his Win32 API call (probably a [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) fail, or will it wait (or whatever) until the copy operation is done?

Comment: I think Windows will synchronize the access to the file, at least write-protect it for the moment. Usually, when accessing an already open file, you will get an error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If somebody requests exclusive access to a file that's already opened, that request will fail. Windows does not have a file open mode that consists of, "If somebody else is using the file, bump him off."

As I recall, `CopyFile` opens the source file so that others can read, but not write it.

Comment: Yeah. I mean, I figured as much. Problem is, the docs make zero mention on the details, hence this question.

Comment: It's an implementation detail, unlikely to be officially documented :)

Comment: The Wine [source for CopyFileExW](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/kernel32/path.c#L936) opens the file with all sharing.  No guarantee that's what Windows does, but Wine aims for high compatibility.