# Copy contents of file without locking file

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am processing large log files (around 40 MB) from Machines. These files are constantly being written to.

I am checking first if a file is changed, then I am using `CopyFile()` to copy it to myself, and then process it. I thought this was okay, but out of 3 Machines, 1 Machine was no longer updating the debug file today.

(only after I used VNC to copy the logs to me did it suddenly start updating)

Is `CopyFile()` somehow blocking the file?

If yes, is there a alternative method to copy a file without locking at all?

```
CopyFile(PChar(source), PChar(dest), FALSE);
```

**UPDATE 1**

Now I use:

```
CopyFileExW(PChar(source), PChar(dest), nil, nil, nil, COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE);
```

Using another very small app, I try to write to the file while the copy is happening:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F : TextFile;
begin
  inc(i);

  try
    AssignFile(F, '\\xxxx\xx\xx\xx\xx\xx\HJobs4.trc');
    try
      if FileExists('\\xxxx\xx\xx\xx\xx\xx\HJobs4.trc') then
        Append(F)
      else
        Rewrite(F);

      Writeln(F, '['+FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd hh:nn:ss',now)+'] '+'WRITE TEST'+' '+i.ToString);
    finally
      CloseFile(F);
    end;
  except
    on E : Exception do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(DateTimeToStr(now)+' '+E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

What I do is I start the copy. This takes a while. And meanwhile, I execute the other App nonstop, and I get a few I/O 103 errors at the start of the copy operation, which is bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does CopyFile place any lock on the source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271010/does-copyfile-place-any-lock-on-the-source-file)

Comment: Maybe it is something in the vicinity of the copy that causes the block. You could post some (relevant) code. Also try to disable AntiVirus products that might interfere.

Comment: @Christian.K : no it does not solve my problem . See EDIT

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this :

```
function TMain.CopyFileAcrossNetwork(source, dest : string): boolean;
var
  SrcStream : TFileStream;
  DestStream : TFileStream;
begin

  SrcStream := TFileStream.Create(Source,fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyNone);
  DestStream := TFileStream.Create(Dest, fmCreate);
  try

    DestStream.CopyFrom(SrcStream);

  finally
    SrcStream.Free;
    DestStream.Free;
  end;
```

This does not block the file .

Comment: That's no solution - it's a whole different approach: it won't copy any file attributes, and it will only check the size to copy at the beginning, not afterwards again. It also won't reserve the whole space at once for the new file.

Comment: @AmigoJack : perhaps  you did not read the question till the end . As I said I have Machine Debug Logs which are non-stopp writen to... I need to copy this to myself without blocking the file. Otherwise the Machine dies . Right now I am doing just that Copying without Blocking . I don't care about file attributes . And I don't care if anything changes after I started... I will get the changes in the next run . If you have a better solution . Please be so kind and help me out. Thank you.

Comment: You chose the wrong question title: you're not interested in `CopyFileW()` but instead in copying content - that's also why this Q is voted as duplicate to a different one already. Also I have no idea why you outline multiple times that it's a "_Machine_" - no, it isn't - it's a storage device. Instead you should have added more tags to your Q so other people subscribed to f.e. [file-copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) would have noticed it.

Comment: @AmigoJack : yes you are right , as I created the question I was hoping to solve this with CopyFile. But since none of them worked I decided I try with FIleStream . I could have written in the Title Copy Contents of File without Blocking . And yes it is a Storage device :) , but since it is integrated tile of a Cuting Machine , I said Machine . Sorry for that and thank you. I guess I can no longer alter the Question Title.

Comment: @AmigoJack : altered the Question Title

Comment: `TStream.CopyFrom()` takes 2 parameters, not 1. If you set the 2nd parameter to a value <= 0 then it will copy the whole file up to the current `Size` (if the file is still being written to while the copy is in progress, anything newly written won't be copied). Also, `+` should be `or` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : thank you , I just checked the System.Classes unit for the CopyFrom . If i understand correctly right now if something changes on the file while copying started it won't be copied .If so than that is trough luck what I wanted :)